# Apache Airflow keeps repeating DAG

Tags: python, docker, airflow

I've been following the steps laid out here https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html to get Apache Airflow set up in Docker. Once set up, I've noticed that the DAG seems to run on a loop without being explicitly told to. The reason I know this is because I've set Python code up to trigger email alerts to me if a given task fails and I'm getting alerts constantly, even when the DAG isn't running in the interface (literally multiple times per minute as long as the server is spun up). I also have CSVs that should update once the steps run and they seem to be refreshing spontaneously (i.e. I can delete the files from the folder and they will appear again soon after without me doing anything).

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you specify `dag = DAG(dag_id=DAG_ID, schedule_interval='* * * * *')`? This will run the DAG once every minute

Comment: My dag is set up as follows. Worth noting that I am shooting for daily refreshes: dag = DAG(dag_id="AIM_Pipeline", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval='@daily', 
          catchup=False)

Comment: Try using `schedule_interval='00 09 * * *'`, this will run at 09:00am every day

Comment: I've probably been slightly vague on this (first time posting!). I'm testing for now so I'd like to set it to run only when I tell it to and for it to not be repeated after the run has completed.

Comment: For manual trigger, it should be `schedule_interval=None`

Comment: So I set that and re-ran the DAG. I'm still getting the same error email multiple times. It's not even showing subsequent runs on the GUI so I don't know what's driving them.

Comment: How about set it to retry only 2 times, see my updated codes

Comment: Something else that's interesting is that I noticed that it seemed to be one task in particular that kept generating the error email. I removed that task from the DAG and I'm still getting error messages for it.

Comment: The scheduler has a backlog of tasks running? Do you know how to kill the scheduler?

Comment: It would seem that way but I don't know why. How would I stop it?

Comment: See if this works `sudo pkill -9 -f "airflow scheduler"`. After that you should try to google for the correct way to shutdown or restart the scheduler

Comment: Upvoted for you.. did you manage to kill the scheduler?

Comment: Would you share any updates on the scheduler? I'm also curious to know :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I have set it up:

```
#Set default arguments
default_args={
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2021,5,27),
    'retries': 0,
    'email': ["rory.wallis@aimsmarter.co.uk"],
    'email_on_failure': True
    }


#Initialise the DAG
dag = DAG(dag_id="AIM_Pipeline", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None, 
          catchup=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The DAG should be specified like this

```
DAG_ID = 'dag_name_here'
start_date = datetime(2020, 11, 30)
default_args = {'owner': 'airflow',
                'depends_on_past': False,
                'retries': 2,
                'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1),
                'start_date': start_date
                }
dag = DAG(dag_id=DAG_ID,
            default_args=default_args,
            schedule_interval = blah   #see options below
            )
```

To run once every minute: `schedule_interval = '* * * * *'`

To run once every day at 09:00am: `schedule_interval = '00 09 * * *'`

To run on manual trigger: `schedule_interval = None`